# How to select the first occurance of a class in all elements with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I select the first tds with notpassed class in this example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="passed">1</td>
        <td class="passed">2</td>
        <td class="passed">3</td>
        <td class="notpassed">4</td>
        <td class="notpassed">5</td>
        <td class="notpassed">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="passed">04:47</td>
        <td class="passed">06:22</td>
        <td class="passed">13:15</td>
        <td class="notpassed">20:07</td>
        <td class="notpassed">20:27</td>
        <td class="notpassed">00:27</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

tr .notpassed:first-child is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
tr > .notpassed{
  color: red;
  /* your selected css style */
}
tr > .notpassed ~ .notpassed{
  color: black;
   /* your common css style */
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="passed">1</td>
        <td class="passed">2</td>
        <td class="passed">3</td>
        <td class="notpassed">4</td>
        <td class="notpassed">5</td>
        <td class="notpassed">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="passed">04:47</td>
        <td class="passed">06:22</td>
        <td class="passed">13:15</td>
        <td class="notpassed">20:07</td>
        <td class="notpassed">20:27</td>
        <td class="notpassed">00:27</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

try nth-child(n) where n is the argument you need to pass, like the number of element (1,2,3) or alosoodd, even

```
.notpassed:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  /* apply the css you want */
}
```

Comment: not working... Please test it in jsfiddle...

Comment: It does work with correct index, try using 4 instead of 1, it works for me